# Python callback inside class

Tags: python, class, function, methods, callback

I'm registering [pysvn.Client.callback_get_login callback](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_callback_get_login), but I want my callback to be defined under my class, as method, rather then global function.

So, in my class I want to have something like:

```
self.client = pysvn.Client()
self.client.callback_get_login = self.get_login
```

instead:

```
self.client = pysvn.Client()
self.client.callback_get_login = get_login
```

But in 1st snippet I'm getting error:

```
pysvn._pysvn_2_7.ClientError: unhandled exception in callback_get_login
```

Is there a way to assign callback that is inside a class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and solve it by creating a closure for my login func :

```
class DummyClient:
   def __init__(self):
      def callback_get_login(realm, username, may_save):
         name = raw_input("Enter your svn login : ")
         password = getpass.getpass("Enter your svn password :")
         return True, name, password, False
      self.client.callback_get_login = callback_get_login
```

Comment: That works. Thanks! Since I store username and password as DummyClient class attributes, I thought I can't access them from closure with self.username and self.password, but I can. Which is good in my case.